# Is there a way to make "folded code" stay folded in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I would like to keep code folded once I've folded it.

When I'm done with a window of code for an Activity I close it. Then when I come back to it, all the code opens up again...
Would be nice if it stayed folded.

Is it possible to keep "folded code" folded in Android Studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here how to set the default behavior

**"File => Settings => Editor => Gerneral => Code Folding => Collapse by default => Method bodies".**

you can also find language-specific options here.

Comment: happy coding 